# What's the use of specification-correct term SimpleType[Type][Type]?

Tags: scala

In the Scala Specs. [Chapter 3](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html), it is written :

```
  Type              ::=  FunctionArgTypes ‘=>’ Type
                      |  InfixType [ExistentialClause]
  FunctionArgTypes  ::=  InfixType
                      |  ‘(’ [ ParamType {‘,’ ParamType } ] ‘)’
  ExistentialClause ::=  ‘forSome’ ‘{’ ExistentialDcl
                             {semi ExistentialDcl} ‘}’
  ExistentialDcl    ::=  ‘type’ TypeDcl
                      |  ‘val’ ValDcl
  InfixType         ::=  CompoundType {id [nl] CompoundType}
  CompoundType      ::=  AnnotType {‘with’ AnnotType} [Refinement]
                      |  Refinement
  AnnotType         ::=  SimpleType {Annotation}
  SimpleType        ::=  SimpleType TypeArgs
                      |  SimpleType ‘#’ id
                      |  StableId
                      |  Path ‘.’ ‘type’
                      |  ‘(’ Types ‘)’
  TypeArgs          ::=  ‘[’ Types ‘]’
  Types             ::=  Type {‘,’ Type}
```

Let's consider the following rewriting:

```
Type

InfixType 

CompundType 

AnnotType 

SimpleType 

SimpleType [Type] 

SimpleType [Type] [Type]
```

So `SimpleType [Type] [Type]` seems a valid type. At least it would be a valid sentence in this grammar, do I understand that correctly?

Is there any use of such type expression?

In other words, is it possible to write a Scala program that has `SimpleType [Type] [Type]` in it and compiles ?

If yes, how? If not, why not?

Unless valid, what is the point of having

`SimpleType  ::=  SimpleType TypeArgs`

in the grammar of Scala?

Comment: Your rewriting sequence seems wrong to me

Comment: What is wrong with it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Parser is just one of compiler's stages, so yes - it will be *grammatically* parsed to AST, but no - it will not be *semantically* valid AST.

Parsed:

```
scala> val a: List[Int][Int] = null
<console>:13: error: List[Int] does not take type parameters
   val a: List[Int][Int] = null
          ^
```

Not parsed:

```
scala> def aaa[A][B]
<console>:1: error: '=' expected but '[' found.
   def aaa[A][B]
             ^

scala> trait A[A][B]
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but '[' found.
       trait A[A][B]
                 ^
```

So, it seems that you can't define such type, but can refer to such. More deeply, scala doesn't fully support type parameters yet (as long as type constructors) - so there is no currying for them now, but it's possible in the future.

UPDATE:

Actually there is an example, where such syntax actually works if you call something applicable:

```
scala> object Def1 { def apply[T] = 0 }
defined object Def1

scala> object Def2 { def apply[T] = Def1 }
defined object Def2

scala> Def2[Int][Int]
res0: Int = 0
```

However, still can't find an example of having `[A][B]` inside type definition, it might be a feature, reserved for the future.

Comment: So the reason why this is in the grammar is to leave the possibility for adding currying for type parameters in the future ?

Comment: So `val a: List[Int][Int] = null` is syntactically correct, but semantically not (yet) ?

Comment: 1) i hope so (it may be just a bug or parser specific workaround), at least they have this excuse now :) 

2) yes

Comment: hm... excuse ? what do you mean ?

Comment: i mean scala's compiler is not simplest compiler in the world, so bugs and workarounds are much possible, but even if it's workaround - it may be used for type parameters currying to define high-order type-constructors's. You can only be sure that this syntax is legal - as parser shows no errors.

Comment: I wonder if there are many similar cases where the parser accepts a certain kind of expression but that expression can never appear in a semantically correct (i.e. compilable) Scala code.

Comment: There are, in fact, many such cases. For example, the grammar prescribes what a method call looks like, but that will only be semantically correct if the method being called actually exists and has the appropriate type and the appropriate access level.

Comment: I see that of course, but the strange thing in this case is that there is no Scala program on earth which contains `A[B][C]` (not as a literal of course) that would ever compile. So why is it allowed in the grammar then at all?